# Opencart: sort products by their subcategory on the category page

Tags: php, opencart

I am building a shop with opencart 1.5.5.1 (I'm new to it) and I ran into a little problem:

Any of my main category pages looks like this:
**Refine search:

    *-Subcategory1

    -Subcategory2

    -Subcategory3*


  Product1  Product2  Product3  ...**

Subcategory 1,2 and 3 being links to the subcategory pages.

What i want my main category page to be like is:

***Subcategory1***

Product1  Product2  Product3  .......
*Subcategory2*
Product1  Product2  Product3  .......
*Subcategory3*
Product1  Product2  Product3  .......

Where Subcategory 1,2 and 3 are no longer links to the subcategory pages but simple text.

I have found this extension: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&token=b4381909f29ca2d2511830b09f09fa84&extension_id=11190 but maybe someone can help me without me having to pay 15$

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Have you installed a custom/new theme or are you using the default opencart theme?

Comment: @BIT CHEETAH - I use the default theme.

Comment: @burhan - I have not tried that much. The are a few posts on opencart forum asking the same thing but there aren't any concrete answers. I tried modifying some php and tpl files from the default theme but without luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

→ Ok so I'm going to go through this step by step, **ask questions between steps or vote this step up if you got it:**

***STEP #1:***

*Open the following file:*

```
catelog/controller/product/category.php
```

**SAVE A BACKUP OF THIS FILE FIRST THEN KEEP GOING!**

*Somewhere around line 271 you should see this:*

```
     $this->data['categories'][] = array(

         'name'  => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),

         'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)

    );
```

*Change the above code to:*

```
     $this->data['categories'][] = array(

          'category_id'  => $result['category_id'], /*!!!*/

          'name'  => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),

          'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)

     );
```

***STEP #2:***

*Open the same file you did in Step 1:*

```
catelog/controller/product/category.php
```

**SAVE A BACKUP OF THIS FILE FIRST THEN KEEP GOING!**

Somewhere around line 271 you should see this:

```
    $this->data['categories'][] = array(

        'category_id'  => $result['category_id'], /*!!!*/

        'name'  => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),

        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)

    );

} 

/* New code will be pasted here! */

$this->data['products'] = array();
```

*Obviously, this is the code we worked on in Step 1, but what your going to do now is copy and paste the following code after that last '}' but before '$this->data['products'] = array();'*

```
$this->data['products_all'] = array();

for( $x = 0; $x < count( $this->data['categories'] ); $x++ ) {

    $cat = $this->data['categories'][ $x ][ 'category_id' ];
    $this->data['products_all'][ $cat ] = array();

    $data = array(
        'filter_category_id' => $cat, 
        'sort'               => $sort,
        'order'              => $order,
        'start'              => ($page - 1) * $limit,
        'limit'              => $limit
    );

    $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data); 
    $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);

    foreach ($results as $result) {

        if ($result['image']) {
            $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_product_height'));
        }
        else { $image = false; }

        if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
            $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
        } 
        else { $price = false; }

        if ((float)$result['special']) {
            $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
        } 
        else { $special = false; }  

        if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
            $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price']);
        }
        else { $tax = false; }              

        if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
            $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
        } 
        else { $rating = false; }

        $this->data['products_all'][ $cat ][] = array(
            'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
            'thumb'       => $image,
            'name'        => $result['name'],
            'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..',
            'price'       => $price,
            'special'     => $special,
            'tax'         => $tax,
            'rating'      => $result['rating'],
            'reviews'     => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
            'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])

        );
    }
}
```

***STEP #3:***

Open the following file:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl
```

**SAVE A BACKUP OF THIS FILE FIRST THEN KEEP GOING!**

*Somewhere around line 19 you should see this:*

```
  <?php if ($categories) { ?>
    <h2><?php echo $text_refine; ?></h2>
    <div class="category-list">
    <?php if (count($categories) <= 5) { ?>
    <ul>
      <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
  <?php } else { ?>
```

*Change the above code to:*

```
  <?php if ($categories) { ?>

    <div class="category-list">

    <?php 

        if ( count( $categories ) <= 5 ) {

            foreach ( $categories as $k=>$category ) { 

                if( $k > 0 ) echo '<br /><br />';

                echo '<div class="product-filter" style="background:#222;padding:5px;padding-bottom:2px">';
                echo '<a href="' . $category['href'] . '" style="font-size:21px;text-decoration:none;"><h2 style="color:#eee;font-style:italic"><span style="color:#777;position:relative;bottom:2px">&rarr;&nbsp;</span><span style="border-bottom:solid 1px #777;">' . $category['name'] . '</span>:</h2></a>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<hr style="border:none;border-top:solid 1px #eee"/>';
                echo '<div class="product-list">';

                foreach ( $products_all[ $category['category_id'] ] as $product )
                {
                    echo '<div>';
                    if ( $product['thumb'] ) {
                        echo '<div class="image"><a href="' . $product['href'] . '"><img src="' . $product['thumb'] . '" title="' . $product['name'] . '" alt="' . $product['name'] . '" /></a></div>';
                    }
                    echo '<div class="name"><a href="' . $product['href'] . '">' . $product['name'] . '</a></div>';
                    echo '<div class="description">' . $product['description'] . '</div>';
                    if ( $product['price'] ) {
                        echo '<div class="price">';
                        if ( !$product['special'] ) { echo $product['price']; } 
                        else { echo '<span class="price-old">' . $product['price'] . '</span> <span class="price-new">' . $product['special'] . '</span>'; }
                        if ( $product['tax'] ) { echo '<br /><span class="price-tax">' . $text_tax . ' ' . $product['tax'] . '</span>'; }
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                    if ( $product['rating'] ) {
                        echo '<div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars-' . $product['rating'] . '.png" alt="' . $product['reviews'] . '" /></div>';
                    }
                    echo '<div class="cart">';
                    echo '<input type="button" value="' . $button_cart . '" onclick="addToCart(\'' . $product['product_id'] . '\');" class="button" />';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="wishlist"><a onclick="addToWishList(\'' . $product['product_id'] . '\');">' . $button_wishlist . '</a></div>';
                    echo '<div class="compare"><a onclick="addToCompare(\'' . $product['product_id'] . '\');">' . $button_compare . '</a></div>';
                    echo '</div>';
              }
              echo '</div>';

            }

      ?>

    <?php } else { ?>
```

Comment: Ok I changed the code in catalog/controller/product/category.php (step 1 complete). Step2?

Comment: Don't You think asnwering for three times and requesting the OP to upvote Your each answer if he gets it is kinda harsh? **You should answer just once and make edits to Your answer.** I am flagging all three of Your answers.

Comment: @shadyyx, No I do not, just because I answered this question did not mean that the answer was sitting on my computer. I knew how to do it but I had to write the code as I did it. If I had not split it up, this question would have been left unanswered as I would not risk doing the entire piece without knowing if the questioner could follow along and complete the work. The upvote request is a measly incentive I had to help Radu which also saved him $15: I highly doubt he would consider my method "kinda harsh;" these are the sort of things that moderators with nothing real to moderate grip about.

Answer (score 0):

What about opencart 2? If i do like you, I get

> Notice: Undefined offset: 60 in ..\category.tpl on line 59 
>   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ..\category.tpl on line 59